# YouTube API How to Get Most Viewed Videos of All Time?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have tried to use the new YouTube API to get the videos with the highest view count of all time.

I have tried to use this request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&maxResults=10&order=viewCount&safeSearch=none&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I thought it would work. It returns 10 videos that have a quite high view count and are sorted in a descending order by view count. However, those videos are definitely not the absolute top 10.

Is there a way to make YouTube API return the real top of most viewed videos?

Comment: How do you know which are the top 10 most videos *(outside of YouTube Data API)*?

Comment: I just checked, the highest view count was 6,139,436,431 views. And I couldn't find a video with more views.